# How to avoid overwriting of a field in avro generic record

Tags: java, avro

Problem  statement:

I  am  having  2  generic  record  object  with  2  different  schema
there  is  single  field   which  is  common  in  both  the  schemas
i   dont  want  to  overwrite  the  value  of  that  particular  field
i  am  trying  something  like  this:

```
for (GenericRecord data1 : record1) {

    for (GenericRecord data2 : record2) {

        GenericData.Record data = new GenericData.Record(finalSchema);

        data1.getSchema().getFields().forEach(field -> data.put(field.name(), data1.get(field.name())));

        data2.getSchema().getFields().forEach(field -> data.put(field.name(), data2.get(field.name())));

        System.out.println(data.toString()); 
    }        
}
```

here  i  need  to  keep  the  field  from  data  1  without  being  overwritten  by  the  field  from  data2

can  anyone  help  me  in  finding  right  solution...

Comment: Please add interpunction to your question. It's kinda hard to read in its current form.

Comment: its  in  readable  format  now i  think ....can  you  please  help  in  finding  a solution...